# Doesn't store entered value when runs second time

Tags: python, list, function, if-statement, random

I made a rock, paper, scissors game.
It works fine, as I wanted to, but it doesn't store entered value when runs second time, how do I fix that.

See the `while` loop below where the program goes again if the user enters `y`.

```
import random

tools =["Rock","Scissors","Paper"]
r = "".join(tools[0])
s = "".join(tools[1])
p = "".join(tools[-1])

def computer_predicion():
    computer_pred = random.choice(tools)
    return computer_pred

computer = computer_predicion()

def my_predicion():
    my_predicion = input("Choose (R)Rock,(S)Scissors,(P)Paper:")
    if my_predicion == "R" or my_predicion == "r":
        my_predicion = r
        return my_predicion
    elif my_predicion == "S" or my_predicion == "s":
        my_predicion = s
        return my_predicion
    elif my_predicion == "P" or my_predicion == "p":
        my_predicion = p
        return my_predicion
    else:
        print("Debils ir?")

human=my_predicion()

def game():
    message_win = ("You won!")
    message_lose = ("You lost!")
    message = "Computer:%s\nUser:%s"%(computer, human)
    if computer == r and human == r :
        print(message+"\nIt's draw")
    elif computer == p and human == p:
        print(message + "\nIt's draw")
    elif computer == s and human == s:
        print(message + "\nIt's draw")
    elif computer == r and human == p:
        print(message+'\n'+message_win)
    elif computer == p and human == r:
        print(message+'\n'+message_lose)
    elif computer == r and human == s:
        print(message+'\n'+message_lose)
    elif computer == s and human == r:
        print(message+'\n'+message_win)
    elif computer == p and human == s:
        print(message+'\n'+message_win)
    elif computer == s and human == p:
        print(message+'\n'+message_lose)
    else:
        pass

c = True
while c:      //Here code runs second time if user inputs Y or y.
    game()
    h = input("Continue?(Y/N):")
    if h == "Y" or h == "y":
        my_predicion()
        computer_predicion()
        pass
    elif h == "N" or h == "n":
        c = False
    else:
        print("Wrong symbol!")
```

Answer (score 1):

The value is not being stored in the second loop because

```
computer = computer_predicion()
human = my_predicion()
```

are displayed outside of the while loop

Here is your working code, I migrated the two variable assignment inside the while loop

```
import random

tools =["Rock","Scissors","Paper"]
r="".join(tools[0])
s="".join(tools[1])
p="".join(tools[-1])
def computer_predicion():
    computer_pred = random.choice(tools)
    return computer_pred

def my_predicion():
    my_predicion = input("Choose (R)Rock,(S)Scissors,(P)Paper:")
    if my_predicion=="R" or my_predicion =="r":
       my_predicion = r
       return my_predicion
    elif my_predicion=="S" or my_predicion =="s":
       my_predicion = s
       return my_predicion
    elif my_predicion=="P" or my_predicion =="p":
       my_predicion = p
       return my_predicion
    else:
         print("Debils ir?")

def game():
    message_win = ("You won!")
    message_lose = ("You lost!")
    message = "Computer:%s\nUser:%s"%(computer,human)
    if computer ==r and human==r :
       print(message+"\nIt's draw")
    elif computer == p and human == p:
       print(message + "\nIt's draw")
    elif computer == s and human == s:
       print(message + "\nIt's draw")
    elif computer == r and human==p:
       print(message+'\n'+message_win)
    elif computer == p and human==r:
       print(message+'\n'+message_lose)
    elif computer == r and human==s:
       print(message+'\n'+message_lose)
    elif computer == s and human==r:
       print(message+'\n'+message_win)
    elif computer == p and human == s:
       print(message+'\n'+message_win)
    elif computer == s and human==p:
       print(message+'\n'+message_lose)
    else:
        pass

c=True
while c :      #Here code runs second time if user inputs Y or y.
  computer = computer_predicion()
  human = my_predicion()
  game()
  h = input("Continue?(Y/N):")
  if h=="Y" or h=="y":
     pass
  elif h=="N" or h=="n":
      c=False
  else:
       print("Wrong symbol!")
```

Comment: Wow, never though it was that easy to fix it 0_0. Thank you !

Comment: But there is problem. While you run this code it asks to input value twice, So to fix that mistake you need to ask for new value after user chooses to continue.

Comment: @IvoSorokins have you fixed that problem yet? Or do you need help still?

Comment: Yes I had to put variables inside functions.